# The Laplace transform $\mathcal L$ is a self-adjoint operator on $L^2(\mathbb R_+)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, improper-integrals, fubini-tonelli-theorems

> Let $\mathbb R_+ = [0, \infty)$ and consider the kernel $K(x,y) = e^{-xy}$ on $\mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R_+$. The associated integral operator on $L^2(\mathbb R_+)$ is called the Laplace transform $\mathcal L$, i.e.
> $$(\mathcal L f)(x) = \int_0^\infty K(x,y) f(y)\, dy$$
> Show that the Laplace transform $\mathcal L$ is a self-adjoint operator on $L^2(\mathbb R_+)$.

This question is similar to [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4304436/a-kfx-int-01-kx-y-fy-dy-for-all-f-in-l20-1-fubinis-t) that I'd asked a few days ago, but the same approach doesn't work since the kernel is not square-integrable - so Fubini's theorem may not be applicable.

---

**My work:** 
We want to show $\langle \mathcal Lf, g\rangle = \langle f, \mathcal Lg\rangle$ for all $f,g\in L^2(\mathbb R_+)$. We have
$$\begin{align*}
\langle \mathcal Lf,g\rangle &= \int_0^\infty \mathcal Lf(x) \overline{g(x)} \, dx\\
&= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-xy} f(y) \overline{g(x)}\, dy\, dx
\end{align*}$$
and
$$\begin{align*}
\langle f, \mathcal L g\rangle &= \int_0^\infty f(x) \overline{\mathcal Lg(x)}\, dx\\ &= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-xy} f(x) \overline{g(y)} \, dy\, dx\\&=  
\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-xy} f(y) \overline{g(x)} \, dx\, dy  
\end{align*}$$
So, we must show $$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-xy} f(y) \overline{g(x)}\, dy\, dx =  \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-xy} f(y) \overline{g(x)} \, dx\, dy $$
This can be done easily if Fubini's theorem is applicable. For Fubini's theorem, we require $$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty |e^{-xy}| |f(y)| |g(x)| \, dx\, dy < \infty$$
By applying Cauchy-Schwarz inequality twice (as in the linked post's answer), I was able to get $$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty |e^{-xy}| |f(y)| |g(x)| \, dx\, dy \le \|f\|_2 \|g\|_2 \left(\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-2xy}\, dx\, dy \right)^{1/2}$$
Unfortunately, $$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-2xy}\, dx\, dy$$ diverges, so this bound is useless.

Two possibilities arise: (i) either Fubini's theorem is applicable, and we must find a stronger bound to show $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty |e^{-xy}| |f(y)| |g(x)| \, dx\, dy < \infty$, or (ii) we must show that the two integrals are equal using some technique other than Fubini's theorem. To me, (ii) seems less likely.

I'd appreciate any help in completing the proof. Thank you!

---

Note:

1. $\mathcal L$ is a bounded bijective operator on $L^2(\mathbb R_+)$, in fact, $\| \mathcal L\| = \sqrt\pi$. The explicit calculations can be found in Rajendra Bhatia's *Notes on Functional Analysis*, Pg. $26-27$, and also in *Setterqvist E., Unitary Equivalence: A New Approach to the Laplace transform and the Hardy operator. Master’s Thesis, Department of Mathematics Lule ̊a University of Technology, 2005:329 CIV* [here](http://ltu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1032398/FULLTEXT01.pdf). Further, see [Post 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507208/mathcall2-norm-of-the-laplace-transform), [Post 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4225773/for-epsilon-0-find-a-b-in-mathbb-r0-such-that-mathcal-l-f-2-2) and [Post 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3620739/how-to-prove-laplace-transform-is-bounded-on-l2-mathbbr).

Comment: Why is $\mathcal L$ a bounded operator? Your kernel is not square integrable, and I don't think $\mathcal L$ is well defined.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Please see my edit (notes and references in the end).

Comment: I didn't know that. Please give  a reference.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It is indeed bounded. A cauchy-schwarz type argument works.

Comment: Thanks for the references.

Comment: @DionelJaime I seriously doubt that. Where does $\sqrt {\pi}$ come from of you are applying C-S inequality?

Comment: Right it was actually just an upper bound of $\sqrt{\pi}$ that I saw once. It comes from a gamma function term.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy A clever application of C-S inequality (see Bhatia's Pg. $26-27$) gives an upper bound of $\sqrt\pi$. For the lower bound of $\sqrt\pi$, one has to do more work (see Post $2$ linked above, a question asked by me sometime back).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an approximation argument.  Since you know that $\mathcal{L}$ is bounded, it suffices to show $\langle \mathcal{L}f, g \rangle = \langle f, \mathcal{L}g \rangle$ for $f,g$ in a dense subspace of $L^2$.  For instance, you can assume that $f,g$ are bounded and have compact support, in which case the hypothesis of Fubini's theorem is obviously satisfied.

Comment: Take $X =[0,1]$ and $f,g\in L^2(X)$. Since $C_c(X)$ is dense in $L^2(X)$, there exist sequences $\{f_n\}$ and $\{g_n\}$ of continuous compactly-supported functions such that $f_n \xrightarrow{L_2} f$ and $g_n \xrightarrow{L_2} g$. We have for all $m,n\in \mathbb N$,
$$\langle \mathcal Lf_n, g_m\rangle = \langle f_n, \mathcal L g_m\rangle$$
Just taking $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}$ won't help, because convergence in $L^2$ does not imply pointwise convergence a.e. Convergence in $L^2$ does imply pointwise convergence a.e. along a subsequence, though. What do I do next?

Comment: @delta-divine Forget about a.e. convergence. This is pure Hilbert space theory. The inner product is jointly continuous and $\mathcal L$ is continuous.

Comment: @MaoWao I understand the continuity of $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ and $\mathcal L$. The thing is, if I write $\lim_{m\to\infty} \langle \mathcal Lf_n, g_m\rangle = \langle \mathcal Lf_n, \lim_{m\to\infty} g_m\rangle$ - what's next? Certainly $\lim_{m\to\infty} g_m$ can be replaced by $g$ only if pointwise convergence is assured, at least a.e. We only know that $\lim_{m\to\infty} \|g_m - g\|_{L^2} = 0$.

Comment: @delta-divine Then you don't seem to understand the continuity of the inner product. If $\xi_n\to \xi$ and $\eta_n\to \eta$ in the Hilbert space (which is $L^2$ in this case, but again, this is completely irrelevant here), then $\langle \xi_n,\eta_n\rangle\to \langle \xi,\eta\rangle$.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much - *now* I understand it @MaoWao! This follows directly from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Thanks again - this is a brilliant idea, Nate!