# Relation between the Hilbert-Hankel operator and Laplace transform on $L^2(\mathbb R_{>0})$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, harmonic-analysis, fubini-tonelli-theorems

> Let $\mathbb R_{>0} = (0, \infty)$. The Hilbert-Hankel operator $H$ is the integral kernel operator on $L^2(\mathbb R_{>0})$ defined as $$(Hf)(x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{f(y)}{x+y}\, dy$$
> Prove that $H = \mathcal L^2$, where $\mathcal L$ is (the Laplace transform) the integral kernel operator on $L^2(\mathbb R_{>0})$ defined as
> $$(\mathcal L f)(x) = \int_0^\infty e^{-xy} f(y)\, dy$$
> Thus, conclude that $\|H\| =  \pi$.

---

**Questions**:

1. The task is to show that $\mathcal L$ is **a** square root of the Hilbert-Hankel operator, i.e. $H = \mathcal L^2$. Is this square root **unique**, i.e. does it make sense to define $H^{1/2}:= \mathcal L$?
2. Is my proof (in particular the applicability of Fubini's theorem) correct? I worry because $\frac{1}{\sqrt x} \to \infty$ as $x\to 0$, so I am not sure if Fubini's theorem is really applicable? Although, we only have to fix $x \in (0, \infty)$ and then evaluate the integrals - in which case, $\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ is certainly just a finite number.
3. So I wonder, are there any interesting results known about $\mathcal L^n$, for $n\in \mathbb N$? Also, can we find the $n$th root of the Hilbert-Hankel operator, i.e. what is $H^{1/n}$ for $n\in \mathbb N$?

---

**My work:**

If $H = \mathcal L^2$, it is easy to see that $\|H\| = \|\mathcal L^2\| = \|\mathcal L\|^2 = \pi$. This follows since $\|\mathcal L\| = \sqrt\pi$ and $\mathcal L$ is self-adjoint, as shown in [this post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306459/the-laplace-transform-mathcal-l-is-a-self-adjoint-operator-on-l2-mathbb-r) For self-adjoint operators $A$ (and more generally, for normal operators) it is true that $\|A\|^2 = \|A^2\|$. The main effort lies in showing $H = \mathcal L^2$.
Directly from definitions, we have $$\begin{align}
\mathcal L^2f(x) &= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-xy-yz} f(z)\, dz\, dy\\ &= \int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-xy-yz} f(z)\, dy\, dz\\
&= \int_0^\infty f(z) \int_0^\infty e^{-xy-yz} \, dy \, dz\\ &= \int_0^\infty \frac{f(z)}{x+z}\, dz\\ &= Hf(x)
\end{align}$$
where we have used Fubini's theorem. Fubini's theorem is applicable because
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-xy-yz} |f(z)| dz dy &\le \|f\|_2 \int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^\infty e^{-2xy-2yz} \, dz\right)^{1/2}\, dy\\ &= \|f\|_2 \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-xy}}{\sqrt{2y}}\, dy \\ &= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}} \|f\|_2 < \infty 
\end{align}$$
for $0 < x < \infty$.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you worry about Fubini, you can also split $f$ into its positive and its negative part and for each of those you can use Tonelli's theorem (as everything is nonnegative).

Comment: Nice, thanks! That should answer Q2. Any idea about the other two?

Comment: Even in $\mathbb{R}$, square roots are not unique. For example $(-1)^2=1=1^2$. For real numbers we usually pick the positive root. Similarly, the square root of an operator becomes unique once you assume that the resulting operator is a positive operator (at least for selfadjoint operators).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your last question, specifically,

> Also, can we find the $n$th root of the Hilbert-Hankel operator, i.e. what is $H^{1/n}$ for $n\in \mathbb N$?

The operator $H$ is also known as the *Carleman operator*.

1. $H$ is self-adjoint and can be explicitly diagonalized, see Yafaev (2010): [A commutator method for the diagonalization of Hankel operators](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.1391). This allows computing $f(H)$ for a wide range of functions $f$.
2. Power (1980): [Hankel Operators on Hilbert Space](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/blms/12.6.422) gives a good overview on the general topic and discusses its relation to the Laplace transform.